# Concurrency control with Entityframework DBFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db-first

I have added RowVersion for concurrency control and set Concurrency mode of this field to Fixed.But when I tried to update that column it shows DbUpdateConcurrencyException even though the row is not updated by another user.

Comment: Are you changing the value of `RowVersion` before you update?

Comment: No,I didn't change anything otherthan a row regarding status

Comment: No..I didn't update rowversion..I have checked the rowversion in db also.It was same.Also,i am using BLtoolkit for query execution.Is there any limitation for this tool?

Comment: I've never heard of that tool.